# How to get same UV Editor view in other workspace?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, workspaces

I'd like to have a UV Editor open in the Shading workspace so I can rotate and scale the unwrapping while I alter the material (instead of having to go back and forth between the two workspaces), but when I naively try and do that, it doesn't show the layout of the model in the UV Editor view.

In other words, I'd like is to get the same info in the UV Editor that I put in the Shading workspace as already exists in the UV Editing workspace - how can I do that?

(Additionally, I'm able to rotate and scale the UV unwrapping in the UV Editor no matter what material it shows, but it'd be nice to have it automatically keep up with the material of the currently selected object - is there a way to do that instead of having to switch to it manually in the UV Editor?)

[image: UV Editing workspace]

[image: Shading workspace]

Answer (score 0):

Found after I actually started getting to work, I keep forgetting you have to go into *Edit Mode* to activate the UV Editor.

Would appreciate if there is a way to make it so the *UV Editor* shows the layout in *Object Mode* though.